# У меня есть задание сделать программу календарь, пытаюсь сделать цикл в функции но выводится undefined

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

```
var getDayOfWeek = function(day, numberDay){
  var week = ['понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота', 'воскресенье'];
  for (var i = week[day]; i <= 31; i++){
    week.push(week[i]);
    var weekDay = week[numberDay]
  }
  return weekDay;
};

getDayOfWeek(10, 20);
```

/*
Напиши для меня программу-календарь.

Оформи программу в виде функции getDayOfWeek. У неё должно быть два параметра: день недели, на который выпадает первое число месяца, и число, для которого нужно найти день недели в этом месяце.

Функция должна возвращать строку с названием для недели. Название должно быть написано с маленькой буквы в именительном падеже: 'понедельник', 'вторник' и так далее.

*/

Comment: `var i = week[day];` - ??

Comment: Ага, а 10 это день недели, на который выпадает первое число месяца. Видимо среда опять))

Comment: igor это день недели с которой должно начинаться рассчет.

Comment: и что там на десятом месте в массиве?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const getDayOfWeek = function(day, numberDay){
  const week = ['понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота', 'воскресенье'];
  return week[(numberDay + day - 1)%7];  // -1 если понедельник это 0, и -2 если понедельник 1 (в аргументах)
  
  }
console.log(getDayOfWeek(1,14));
```

А так, если вводить по названию:

```js
const getDayOfWeek = function(day, numberDay){
  const week = ['понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота', 'воскресенье'];
  return week[(numberDay + week.indexOf(day) - 1)%7];  
  
}
  
console.log(getDayOfWeek('понедельник', 3));
```

Comment: - 1 и -2 это компенсация перевода с нашего [1,2,3...] на JS [0,1,2...]